# ORDER BY a renamed field in Access 2010?

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, ms-access-2010

Can it be done? I have:

```
    SELECT EventName, ClientLastName +', '+ ClientFirstName AS ClientName,
    EmpLastName +', '+ EmpFirstName AS ProgSupName
    FROM Employee, Salary, Events, Client, EventsScheduled, ISL, ProgramSupervisor
    WHERE Events.EventNo = EventsScheduled.EventNo
    AND EventsScheduled.ClientNo = Client.ClientNo
    AND Client.ISLNo = ISL.ISLNo
    AND Employee.EmpNo = Salary.EmpNo
    AND Salary.EmpNo = ProgramSupervisor.EmpNo
    AND ProgramSupervisor.EmpNo = ISL.ProgramSupervisor_EmpNo
    AND Events.EventStartDate BETWEEN #11/20/2013# AND #12/30/2014#
    ORDER BY ????
```

I want to ORDER BY ProgSupName but it throws an error. Any ideas?

Comment: You can just duplicate the definition of `ProgSupName`, so `Order By EmpLastName + ', ' + EmpFirstName`. Not ideal, but I don't think Access lets you use an alias.

Comment: I tried that but it's not giving me the output I thought it would. A program supervisor's name is shown for a few records then a different program supervisor's name is shown then it goes back to listing the first program supervisor's name. The records aren't being grouped all at once by the program supervisor's name.

Comment: I think to concatenate strings in MSAccess you use `&` rather than `+`

Comment: @Laurence I haven't had problems using + in the past. It's been working in this database.

Comment: Oh, that's only a problem if one operand is numeric and one is a string. In that case + tries to coerce the second to a number and & converts the number to an string, apologies.

Comment: Did you try `ORDER BY 3`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid duplicating the definition of `ProgSupName`, one way is to

```
select
    *
from (
    select
        EventName, 
        ClientLastName & ", " & ClientFirstName as ClientName,
        EmpLastName & ", " & EmpFirstName as ProgSupName
    from
        Employee em
            inner join 
        Salary s
            on em.EmpNo = s.EmpNo
            inner join
        ProgramSupervisor p
            on s.EmpNo = p.EmpNo
            inner join
        ISL i
            on p.EmpNo = i.ProgramSupervisor_EmpNo
            inner join
        Client c
            on c.ISLNo = i.ISLNo
            inner join
        EventsScheduled es
            on es.ClientNo = c.ClientNo
            inner join
        Events e
            on e.EventNo = es.EventNo
    where 
        e.EventStartDate between #11/20/2013# and #12/30/2014#
    ) as x
order by
    ProgSupName
```

Comment: So using a nested query will permit Odering by ProgSupName? I appreciate the code, I'll try it out. By the way, do you have a site you'd recommend for SQL basics? I'd like to read up on the basics a bit more so I don't always have to turn to SO. Thanks

Comment: When I was learning about databases, they usually came with paper manuals, I'm not sure about a basic site.